# How to add s/mime certificate to existing contact in outlook2013 easily

Tags: certificate, outlook-2013, smime

i was wondering if any of you know of an easy (and working) way of importing a new mail certificate to an already existing contact (holding an also already existing different mail cert) in Outlook 2013.

The problem was already discussed in https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a5fb1ee0-8abe-4581-ab03-857022783516/adding-an-smime-certificate-to-an-existing-contact-in-outlook-2013?forum=outlook . I tried all the solutions mentioned but the only one that seems to work properly is the painful path of exporting the cert and import it to the contact manually.

Does anybody know of an easier way to achieve that?